# Accessing MySQL Database on XAMPP From a Remote Machine

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jdbc

I am trying to access a my MySQL database thorugh a program I have written that is currently being stored and run on XAMPP on my local machine. I'd like to connect to it from a different machine that is on the same network so they can access the database read/write etc. I am however having no luck in connecting. I've packaged the Java program into an exe that I am running on the remote machine. I've tried a number of solutions already;

1. I've created a user in PHPMyAdmin that can connect from any host, and has all priveleges granted on the database in question.
2. I've edited my program for the remote machine so that `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/sdcjobs";` is now `"jdbc:mysql://(theipaddressofmymachine)/sdcjobs";`
3. I've edited my ini file (C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini) so that bind address is uncommented as now `bind-address=0.0.0.0`

One of the main question marks for me is what software needs to be installed on the remote machine. On my machine (the one thats running the server) I have XAMPP installed that is running an Apache server and a MySQL database. On the remote machine I've installed nothing aside from my Java program, does the remote machine also need MySQL installing on it?

Comment: try to disable firewall in your host machine to see if it works.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ, the firewall is disabled on both machines

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect to your remote database with tools like mysql workbench or heidisql? If this does not work too, it could be a configuration issue in your my.ini

Please don't forget to restart your mysql service after changing your config.

Take a look at the mysql docu: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-connecting.html